# Limesurvey 2.05 plugin

Tags: limesurvey

Edit: Now it's working, was an bug in LimeSurvey.

I created simple login plugin for LimeSurvey 2.05beta5 just to test, if it is working.

Problem is, that event newUserSession is never called. Documentation is also really bad, because is still in beta...

Here is the plugin code:

```
<?php
    class TestLogin extends AuthPluginBase
    {
        protected $storage = 'DbStorage';    

        static protected $description = 'Testing login system...';
        static protected $name = 'TestLogin';

        public function __construct(PluginManager $manager, $id) {
            parent::__construct($manager, $id);

            $this->subscribe('beforeLogin');
            $this->subscribe('newUserSession');
        }

        public function beforeLogin()
        {      
        if (isset($_GET["testlogin"]) && ($_GET["testlogin"] == 1)) {  
            $this->setUsername('admin');
            $this->setAuthPlugin();
        }
        }

        public function newUserSession()
        {
            $sUser = $this->getUserName();        
            $oUser = $this->api->getUserByName($sUser);

            if (!is_null($oUser))
            {
                $this->setAuthSuccess($oUser);
                return;
            } else {
                $this->setAuthFailure(self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID);
            }       
        }   
    }
?>
```

To call this code, just go to this url: admin/authentication/sa/login?testlogin=1

I'm missing something?

Comment: Please leave the "now working" as an answer (below), and accept it so that the question will be marked as solved. Also please reference the issue / ticket / changeset with an identifier and/or link so that a reference is kept. Thank you for making this website (and limesurvey) better!

Comment: LimeSurvey 2.05beta5 .... beta is beta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

now working

Here is working solution: https://github.com/LimeSurvey/LimeSurvey/commit/9df25ebcdb44d32295f64e5996d13fddf12e4bb6